# What to do with 100% datapoints when conducting a Logit transformation

Tags: regression, logistic, data-transformation, panel-data, logarithm

I have a panel dataset of 120 different countries measuring a variable over three periods. This variable indicates the percentage of 1000 respondents in each country that answered yes to the question. I am considering this representative of the probability that a respondent in each country will answer yes to that question. The dataset currently has a bimodal distribution across countries, with the results concentrated around 0.0-0.10 and 0.9-1.0. To transform this into a normal distribution, I am using a logit transformation employing the function

$$\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$

where p is the probability of a respondent answering yes.
However, in three of the countries, 100% of the respondents answered yes, resulting in a logit function that cannot be calculated of

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{1-1}\right)$$

What should I do with these three countries in the sample? Is there a legitimate way to lower their values from 1.0 so that they can be used in the formula?

I will also be averaging the panel data over the three periods to create a cross-sectional data set. The three countries of concern have values of 1.0 in a single period, with their results being less than 1.0 in the other two periods, meaning their average probability would be less than 1. Would it be appropriate for me to average the probability values across the periods prior to employing the logit transformation? an example of these two options is formulated below.

$$\log\left(\frac{p_1 +p_2 + p_3}{3-\left(p_1 +p_2 + p_3\right)}\right)$$

Or

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}\right) + \log\left(\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}\right) + \log\left(\frac{p_3}{1-p_3}\right)}{3}$$

Comment: One solution worth considering is to model the actual counts rather than the percentages.  This has many advantages, not least of which is that the precision of a count is inversely proportional to the count itself--valuable information that is lost when converting to a percentage.

Comment: Why do you need "to transform this into a normal distribution"?

Comment: The idea of using the count itself is interesting and I will test it in my analysis. However, currently using the average of the Logit of my probability variable and the Logit of the average of my probability variable both yield strong results when I simply exclude the three probabilities of 1.0 so I would like to calculate my results with the complete sample in this form.

Comment: I need to transform this into a normal distribution as I am using my variable in linear regression analysis to explain a normally distributed dependent variable. My variable is being compared with the average log of GDP per capita in its explanatory capability. The Logit transformation effectively transforms my variable from bimodal distribution to a normal distribution, allowing linear regression analysis just as the transformation of GDP per capita does.

Comment: Linear regression does not require predictors ($X$) to be normal, so I am skeptical that you need to transform to normality.

Comment: Linear regression does not require predictors to be normal. However, my dependent variable is a normally distributed, limitless variable, as is log GDP per capita. My variable of interest, in its base form is limited from 0 to 1, resulting in the concentration of values at the limits. converting the probability into odds [p/(1-p)] fixes this issue. However, it creates an exponential effect as cases probabilities near 1. Taking the log of the odds removes this exponential effect.

Comment: You are still getting a highly bimodal, far from normal, distribution of that predictor "p"; you're just stretching it out at the extremes. Just using the original "p" predictors might work just as well. If it doesn't, you might consider flexible modeling of that predictor in a way that doesn't blow up at "p" = 0 and "p" = 1, like regression splines.